# Haskell - Bool expression in where not evaluating when expected

Tags: haskell, boolean, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I am implementing a simple wack-a-mole game and the function for checking
if a mole is currently popped out of the ground and/or being hit had a baffling
problem that I fixed but I don't know why the original didn't work.

Here is the function:

```
--
-- update a single mole. this will be a mappable function with current time and mouse pos as the partially
-- applied args of the function mapped over the list of moles
--
updateMole :: Point -> Double -> Mole -> Mole
updateMole mousePos time mole@(mtype, pos, uptime, up, wasHit) = 
  (mtype, pos, uptime, isUp, gotHit)
  where
    upDuration = mDurationUp !! (fromEnum mtype)
    isUp = if (time > uptime) && (time<(uptime+upDuration)) 
           then True
           else False  
    -- mole is hit if mouse click within bounding box *and* mole is up.
    gotHit = if isUp==True && wasHit==False
             then
                (  ((fst mousePos) > (fst topCorner)) && ((fst mousePos) < (fst botCorner)) &&
                    ((snd mousePos) < (snd topCorner)) && ((snd mousePos) > (snd botCorner))  )
             else 
                wasHit       
    topCorner = ((fst (holeLocations !! pos)) + (fst hdTopLeft), (snd (holeLocations !! pos)) + (snd hdTopLeft))
    botCorner = ((fst (holeLocations !! pos)) + (fst hdBotRight), (snd (holeLocations !! pos)) + (snd hdBotRight))
```

gotHit will never end up being true.

The fix was to change:

```
gotHit = if isUp==True && wasHit==False
```

to

```
gotHit = if up==True && wasHit==False
```

I don't see why the first way is a problem though. Shouldn't "isUp" get evaluated 
when it needs to be?
You can probably imagine the information overload and completely tangent information
when trying to google things like "haskell Bool not evaluated in where clause"

If the full context of the program actually matters here, it's at:
https://code.world/haskell#PK2k3jAAQLehe540gT0JV1g

Comment: `up` and `isUp` are two different values; this looks more like you were using the wrong one to define `gotHit` rather than `isUp` not being defined when you needed it.

Comment: Unrelated minor point: `if x then True else False` is just `x`. You could also avoid many of those `fst`, `snd` by using an `@`-pattern as the one you are already using, e.g. `mousePos@(mouseX, mouseY)`, and/or using `case of` to name both components of a pair. This is not important, though: you can always learn different code styles later on, for now you can focus on getting your code right.

Comment: @chepner: isUp becomes the new "up" though (see the "returned" value).

Also chi is correct. My "first pass" type code tends to be pretty terrible and verbose like that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That function in isolation probably is misleading in that you don't realize that some of the values become the new state that ends up getting passed in the next interval.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up having nothing to do with order of evaluation, lazy evaluation
or any of that.

It was the fact that two different events in the game were mapping to that function and essentially interfering with each other.

```
     TimePassing x      -> let newMoles = map (updateMole (-1000,0) (clock/100)) moles 
                           in World (clock+1) lvl newMoles msg score 
     PointerPress (x,y) -> let checkedMoles = map (updateMole (x,y) clock) moles
                           in World clock lvl checkedMoles msg score
```

The fix is either what I said, or a better one might be to have two separate functions - one to handle the time interval, the other to handle the pointer event.